# swapExactTokensForETH transaction reverted, `UniswapV2: K` error (with gas wasting), selling with Uniswap GUI works fine

Tags: web3js, erc-20, uniswap, fees

Facing reverting `swapExactTokensForETH` transaction using web3js. Tried different ways. Probably, it is important to note, this failed transaction uses a relatively large amount of Gas Fees. The code contains relevant comments on my actions.

*Additional Info:*

- Performing transaction on Goerli Testnet.
- ERC20 Token have fees on it.
- Approve is done and allowance exceeds the token balance on userAddress.
- *Selling* with Uniswap GUI works fine
- `swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens` also leads to fail transaction *(see comments)*

### Code:

```
// sell all tokens on userAddress
const amountIn = web3.utils.toBN(tokenBalance); // str;

// even tried to sell 99% of tokens, multiplying balance by 99 and divide by 100
// const amountIn = web3.utils.toBN(tokenBalance).muln(99).divn(100); 

const path = [tokenAddress, WETH_ADDRESS]; // token -> WETH -> correct! 
const to = userAddress; // str; -> correct!

console.log(`[debug] userAddress: ${to} | tokenAddress: ${tokenAddress} | tokenBalance: ${amountIn} type ${typeof tokenBalance}`)

const deadline = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 60 * 20; // 20 minutes from now

// get expected output amount of ETH for the given input amount of tokens
let amountsOut = await uniswapRouter.methods.getAmountsOut(amountIn, path).call(); // -> correct!
// set the minimum output amount of ETH to allow (for slippage)
let amountsOutMin = web3.utils.toBN(amountsOut[1]).muln(50).divn(100); // 50% slippage

// also tried -> amountsOut = 0; -> expecting 0 ETH without slippage

// do some double checking, jesus christ
amountsOutMin = amountsOutMin.toString(); // ensure it's a string
amountsOut = amountsOut[1].toString();

console.log(`[debug] amountOutMin: ${amountsOutMin} type ${typeof amountsOutMin}`) // str; -> correct
// (this done only for logs) double check amount in ether decimals -> correct
console.log(`[debug] amountOut ${web3.utils.fromWei(amountsOut, 'ether')} | amountOutMin: ${web3.utils.fromWei(amountsOutMin, 'ether')}`)


const uniswapTx = uniswapRouter.methods.swapExactTokensForETH(amountIn, amountsOutMin, path, to, deadline);

console.log(`[debug] Signing swapExactTokensForETH TX and sending it...`);

const signedUniswapTx = await web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction({
    to: ROUTER_ADDRESS,
    data: uniswapTx.encodeABI(),
    gas: 300000,
    nonce: await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(userAddress),
    gasPrice: await web3.eth.getGasPrice()
}, privateKey);

const uniswapTxReceipt = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signedUniswapTx.rawTransaction);
```

### Debug Output:

```
[debug] Token Balance is 2135600562248108254290491 type string 
[debug] Current Allowance is 10502530986238558623020863 type string 
[debug | approve] Already Approved! 
[debug] userAddress: 0x41eda0CDEa3760559155e37876a60523Ae10160b | tokenAddress: 0xe4756DCAAddA08Adf71d12Bef45A3A775A24188C | tokenBalance: 2135600562248108254290491 type string 
[debug] amountOutMin: 4771974393946051 type string
[debug] amountOut 0.009543948787892103 | amountOutMin: 0.004771974393946051 
[debug] Signing swapExactTokensForETH TX and sending it... 

Uncaught (in promise) Error: Transaction has been reverted by the EVM:
{
  "blockHash": "0x430cfa25d550ec489f367040ba614eb5770289dd1383b63110c19ebf0045e7bd",
  "blockNumber": 8612201,
  "contractAddress": null,
  "cumulativeGasUsed": 1696866,
  "effectiveGasPrice": 121411886765,
  "from": "0x41eda0cdea3760559155e37876a60523ae10160b",
  "gasUsed": 280950,
  "logs": [],
  "logsBloom": "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "status": false,
  "to": "0x7a250d5630b4cf539739df2c5dacb4c659f2488d",
  "transactionHash": "0x5418fdb8469e8cffd1f7cb97ab9e6a9009ab62b661b4582aa05a4e0f0ccd9289",
  "transactionIndex": 12,
  "type": "0x0"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For selling tokens with fees use [swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens](https://docs.uniswap.org/contracts/v2/reference/smart-contracts/router-02#swapexacttokensforethsupportingfeeontransfertokens).

Comment: Unfortunately, switching method to `swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens` doesn't make any sense in my case. Now transaction is failing due to `Warning! Error encountered during contract execution [out of gas]` according to etherscan. It also used 0.072 ETH for gas fees. [TX Link](https://goerli.etherscan.io/tx/0x235e3fd0ae1e06f61414ea76bf4e3975818b1e135748e1dd5bdab6212b8ba672)

Comment: Why does it not make sense in your case? You mentioned you're swapping an ERC20 token with fees - this is exactly what this function is for. | If you plugin your tx in Tenderly debugger, you can see that it looks pretty good, but just fails in the final transfer because it did ran out of gas. There is a gas-expensive swap done by PUMPKIN which takes a lot of the gas. Maybe indeed it simply ran out of gas? I would try giving it some more. You can also use local testnet forking to test without spending real Goerli ETH.

Comment: Note that in these Safemoon-like tokens you need to have the Uniswap router an exception to the swapping of fees, otherwise it'll get to an infinite loop. Judging by the Tenderly debugger I don't think this is what happened in your case, but mentioning it just in case.

Comment: And, if you own the PUMPKIN contract, it would help if you verify it's code on Etherscan, as then you can debug that part also in Tenderly. And make sure it's not doing anything funky like spending all your gas on purpose.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation. And thank you for the tip. I will study this issue in detail. Really grateful for your time.

Comment: I got a successful transaction without forcing the limit up, just using the `estimateGas` function. And this is probably the best way to calculate the gas limit. Just a bit more on that: I see `swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens` takes much more gas fees than a transaction performed with Uniswap GUI App which is uses `execute` through _Universal Router_. The cause, however, is not the Gas Limit or the router, but the actual `gasPrice`. The gui app calculation uses a fairly low gas price (~5 gwei) while `getGasPrice()` returns significantly more value like ~110+ gwei.